# Select count(*) IN ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, count

I'm trying to execute the below code to update tables but cannot get the `count(*)` result in `CNT` variable.

How can i get the number of record in the tables before my update please ?

The error i get executing the below code :

`Error report - ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error ORA-06512: at line 12 06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"`

```
DECLARE
tname varchar(255);
sql1 VARCHAR2(2000);
CNT INTEGER;

CURSOR myCursor IS select table_name from user_tables where table_name like '%VTS';
BEGIN
    OPEN myCursor;
    LOOP
        FETCH myCursor INTO tname;
        EXIT WHEN myCursor%NOTFOUND;
        BEGIN
          CNT:= 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || tname || ' where rownum=1';
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CNT';
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'Number of rows = : ' || CNT);           
         IF ( CNT ) > 0 THEN 
            SELECT column_name INTO sql1 FROM user_tab_cols WHERE table_name = tname AND table_name not in (select view_name from user_views) and data_type ='VARCHAR2' ;
            sql1 := 'UPDATE ' || tname || ' SET '|| sql1 || '=''hello''';     
             EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql1;              
        END IF; 
        END;   
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE myCursor; 
END;
```

Comment: On a side note: Is there only one varchar2 column in these tables? Otherwise `SELECT column_name INTO sql1` will fail.

Comment: Also on a side note, `IF ( CNT ) > 0` can be written more simply as `if cnt > 0`, and I strongly recommend using consistent indentation and avoiding block capitals when writing computer code in general.

Comment: `CNT INTEGER;` and then `CNT:= 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || tname || ' where rownum=1';` can't work because you can only assign a numeric value to `cnt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `execute immediate` with into clause.
Here is the adjusted procedure:

```
DECLARE
tname varchar(255);
sql1 VARCHAR2(2000);
sql2 VARCHAR2(1000);
CNT NUMBER;

CURSOR myCursor IS select table_name from user_tables where table_name like '%VTS';
BEGIN
    OPEN myCursor;
    LOOP
        FETCH myCursor INTO tname;
        EXIT WHEN myCursor%NOTFOUND;
        BEGIN
         sql2 := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || tname;
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql2 INTO CNT;       
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'Number of rows = : ' || CNT);           
         IF ( CNT ) > 0 THEN 

            SELECT column_name 
              INTO sql1 
              FROM user_tab_cols
             WHERE table_name = tname 
               AND table_name not in (select view_name from user_views) 
               AND data_type = 'VARCHAR2';

           sql1 := 'UPDATE ' || tname || ' SET '|| sql1 || '=''hello''';     
           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'sql');           
         END IF; 
        END;   
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE myCursor; 
END;
```

Supplementary remarks:

1. You don't need rownum = 1 when you select just COUNT(*).
2. You need better naming for the variables.

Comment: thanks a lot, it's works perfectly thanks for remarks i will edit my code thanks

Comment: *You don't need rownum = 1 when you select just COUNT(\*)* - you do if the table could contain a hundred million rows and the code only cares whether it contains a row or not.

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic counting logic can be written more cleanly as

```
declare
    tname      varchar(255);
    count_sql  varchar2(500);
begin
    for r in (
        select table_name, num_rows from user_tables -- where table_name like '%VTS'
    )
    loop
        count_sql := 'select count(*) from ' || r.table_name || ' where rownum = 1';

        execute immediate count_sql into r.num_rows;

        dbms_output.put_line('Number of rows in '||r.table_name||' = '||r.num_rows);
    end loop;
end;
```

In the Oracle HR sample schema, that gives output as

```
Number of rows in REGIONS = 1
Number of rows in COUNTRIES = 1
Number of rows in LOCATIONS = 1
Number of rows in DEPARTMENTS = 1
Number of rows in JOBS = 1
Number of rows in EMPLOYEES = 1
Number of rows in JOB_HISTORY = 1
```

The part about updating every `varchar2` column is more complicated, because you can't just fetch the varchar2 column for each table if there is more than one varchar2 column. For example, say table `locations` has   `street_address`, `postal_code`, `city` and `state_province`. You could loop through each row in user_tab_columns and generate four statements as

```
update locations set street_address = 'hello'
update locations set postal_code = 'hello'
update locations set city = 'hello'
update locations set state_province = 'hello'
```

but of course that would be horribly inefficient when what you really wanted was

```
update locations
set    street_address = 'hello'
     , postal_code = 'hello'
     , city = 'hello'
     , state_province = 'hello'
```

You can generate this of course, but it's more complicated. Perhaps something like this (I have replaced `execute immediate` with `dbms_output.put_line` so I can just preview the generated SQL without executing it):

```
declare
    tname      varchar(255);
    count_sql  varchar2(500);
    update_sql varchar2(500);
    l_separator varchar2(2);
begin
    for t in (
        select table_name, num_rows from user_tables -- where table_name like '%VTS'
    )
    loop
        count_sql := 'select count(*) from ' || t.table_name || ' where rownum = 1';

        execute immediate count_sql into t.num_rows;

        dbms_output.put_line('Number of rows in '||t.table_name||' = '||t.num_rows);

        if t.num_rows > 0 then
            update_sql := 'update '||t.table_name||' set ';

            l_separator := '';

            for c in (
                select column_name
                from   user_tab_columns
                where  table_name = t.table_name
                and    table_name not in (select view_name from user_views)
                and    data_type = 'VARCHAR2'
                and    data_length > 4
            )
            loop
                update_sql := update_sql || l_separator || c.column_name||' = ''hello''';
                l_separator := ', ';
            end loop;

            --execute immediate update_sql;
            dbms_output.put_line(update_sql);            
        end if; 

    end loop;
end;
```

which gives me:

```
Number of rows in REGIONS = 1
update REGIONS set REGION_NAME = 'hello'
Number of rows in COUNTRIES = 1
update COUNTRIES set COUNTRY_NAME = 'hello'
Number of rows in LOCATIONS = 1
update LOCATIONS set STREET_ADDRESS = 'hello', POSTAL_CODE = 'hello', CITY = 'hello', STATE_PROVINCE = 'hello'
Number of rows in DEPARTMENTS = 1
update DEPARTMENTS set DEPARTMENT_NAME = 'hello'
Number of rows in JOBS = 1
update JOBS set JOB_ID = 'hello', JOB_TITLE = 'hello'
Number of rows in EMPLOYEES = 1
update EMPLOYEES set FIRST_NAME = 'hello', LAST_NAME = 'hello', EMAIL = 'hello', PHONE_NUMBER = 'hello', JOB_ID = 'hello'
Number of rows in JOB_HISTORY = 1
update JOB_HISTORY set JOB_ID = 'hello'
```